# How to test file permissions using shell script?

Tags: bash, permissions, test

I am testing if my file has read permissions, by running this script as root:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILE="/etc/shadow"

if ! [ -r $FILE ]; then
  echo "Hello"
fi

exit 0
```

Ideally, script has to print `Hello` as there is no Read permission. But, it is not happening.

```
ls -ltrh /etc/shadow
---------- 1 root root 7.1K Jun  7 06:59 /etc/shadow
```

What needs to be modified in script?

Comment: Do you run your script as root? Root will still able to read the files with no read permissions. Just use `ls` or `namei` to read file permissions.

Comment: @Su_scriptingbee Works here `[11:16:01][kristjan] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ bash script.bash 
Hello`

Comment: @somethingSomething because you're not running it as root :D

Comment: @deimos ok cool

Comment: @deimos am running the script as root. Here, I would like to implement ' if a file does not have Read permission'.

Comment: @Su_scriptingbee your current script logic is "Can i read the content of the file?". You need to change it to "Does the file has `r` permission?" or switch from root to a non-privileged user.

Comment: The effect of permissions is dependent on the user. Root is not bothered by not having read permissions, and the `-r` test is therefore always true.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain that you are not trying to test if you can read the file but are trying to figure out the read permissions. As you can see from the answers, the two are quite different.

Answer (score 9):

Check info on permissions on directory or a file or a link

```
stat -L -c "%a %G %U" FILE or DIRECTORY
```

Comment: This is great - exactly what I need to save permissions/owner and set them later!

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILE="/etc/shadow"

if ! [[ $(stat -c "%A" $FILE) =~ "r" ]]; then
  echo "Hello"
fi

exit 0
```

This will check if the file has read permission instead of checkinf if the file is readable by your current user.